# UICollectionView: Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting this error.  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell label]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1eead660'` I am using a nib file as my cell and trying to displays the cells correctly. I am guessing that I am not returning cells correctly, but I am not too sure. Any help will be appreciated.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableArray *data = [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    cell.label.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UICollectionViewCell doesn't have a property called `label`.

Perhaps you meant:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Assuming you subclassed `UICollectionViewCell`, added `label`, and called your subclass `Cell`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed it by accident.

Answer (score 2):

Your nib file probably needs to be connected to your custom class ('Cell'?) somehow. That done, you'd call:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

As it stands right now, you are getting a vanilla `UICollectionViewCell` object back from `dequeue...`, and when you try to use it as a `Cell`, you get problems.

BTW, generally, your `registerClass` code should not go in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. It only needs to be called once per view, e.g.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

@implementation YourCollectionViewController

// ...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [self.collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];   
}

// ...

@end
```

Comment: How to connected to your custom class with story board? thanks!

Comment: @herbertD That sounds like a possibly related, but different question. You can ask it by creating a new question. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.